# Bash script failing to rename folder with date

Tags: bash

My old backup script had the following lines to rename the backup directory with the date of the backup:

```
today=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`
mv /media/DATA/Backup\ yzT\ * /media/DATA/Backup\ yzT\ $today
```

It worked without any problem. Now that I've been editing the script, adding more directories to backup I wanted to declare a variable for the backup directory:

```
today=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`
BACKUPDIR=/media/DATA/Backup\ yzT\ $today
mv /media/DATA/Backup\ yzT\ * $BACKUPDIR
```

This way, I'd only need to edit this variable if in the future I change the backup directory.

However, the `mv`is failing and I don't know why.It's like if it only was taking the $today instead of the whole path, because the output is:

`mv: target ‘2015-03-13’ is not a directory`

An echo of $BACKUPDIR shows the whole path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of escaping spaces better you quote variables:

```
today=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
BACKUPDIR="/media/DATA/Backup yzT $today"
mv /media/DATA/Backup\ yzT\ * "$BACKUPDIR"
```

Otherwise shell is interpreting string before space a different argument and date part after space a different argument.

Comment: what a mistake I did xD. I tried with the double quotes as well, but forgot to remove the '\' when I did so...xD